# 14-30P to dual 5-15/20R splitter

Tags: wiring, receptacle

I have a dryer outlet that is not in use as the dryer is gas fired and only needs a 120V circuit/plug.

I want to get a couple of 120V circuits out of that dryer plug (without rewiring the actual receptacle).

There are [ready-made splitters](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/ac-works--1-5ft-10-4-nema-14-30p-4-prong-dryer-plug-to-4-nema-5-15-20r-connector/1001632855) for such but they seem pretty pricey.

Is there really enough hardware in that to justify $100?

Knowing that a 14-30 is two hots (from each pole in the panel) a neutral and a ground, isn't everything already present to just split that circuit up into two single pole 120V 15A circuits?  In other words, isn't this just a wiring exercise?

For peace of mind, I might just buy the splitter but regardless, my curiosity is piqued.

Comment: They seem to be missing fuses/breakers to limit the amps to around 15.  If something happen then the device could pull the full 30 amps before the breaker will trip.  There should be better ones with fuses/breakers that will be safer.  Also did not see any testing lab marks on them.  Without those marks your insurance can be denied.

Comment: AC Works makes a lot of adapters that will technically *work* but are not safe, particularly if you plan to leave this unattended. Even if you do find one with circuit breakers, it falls in to the category of 'extension cord' and won't be suitable for permanent use.

Comment: The one I provided the link to the photo of was sold at Home Depot.  Would HD actually sell non-compliant devices?  Isn't that a legal problem for them if they are?  (I.e. meaning they likely would not be selling something that would be illegal for them to sell)

Comment: It's more that this falls in to the category of being an extension cord that matters. There's a handful of things you can do with extension cords and adapters for temporary situations which are not suitable to do when you're planning to leave something in place.

Comment: And yes, HD sells electrical hardware that has not been through full lab certification. All their plug-in holiday stuff generally falls into that category. It's not a liability issue because they are not the manufacturer.

Comment: Also as I alluded to in my answer, you won't end up with a GFCI, and in a laundry room that is dangerous as well.

Answer (score 5):

Unless you find an adapter with circuit breakers in it, it is not safe to use.

If you can't find a safe adapter, the correct way to do this involves some wiring. The way is to convert the circuit in to a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC) using the existing wire. You can search around the site for more info on how a MWBC works. The short version is this:

- Replace the two-pole 30A breaker with a two-pole 15A or 20A breaker. This must have the handles tied together. Run the black and red wires from your dryer circuit to the new smaller breaker.
- Replace the 14-30 outlet at the dryer outlet with two duplex 15A or 20A receptacles. One is wired to red and white, the other is wired to black and white. Both of course get ground. Pigtails will be required for the wiring as it's unlikely your receptacles will take 10ga directly. You might need to use the existing receptacle location as a junction box and run new wiring to another box to have enough room for all the wire and devices you will need.

Now you have a safe and code-compliant* installation with two regular 120V circuits using the existing wiring. It's also very reversible if you ever decide it's time to switch to a heat pump dryer.

(you may ask why the caveat on 'code-compliant' there? Because MWBC and AFCI or GFCI circuits don't interact well, and you might need those depending on local code and rules - you might need to install GFCI receptacles instead of regular duplex because laundry rooms tend to have water in them)

Comment: I agree with this answer 100%. For future readers, it's important to note that this works _only_ because the OP has a NEMA 14-30 receptacle that has a neutral. Many washing machines are installed with a NEMA 10-30 receptacle that does _not_ have a neutral (and hasn't been code legal since 1996 for new installs, but is grandfathered in for existing installs). Without that neutral wire, this conversion is not possible without pulling new wire.